# What is the purpose of defining an operator class when defining index in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

For example

```
CREATE INDEX my_index_name
    ON public.my_table USING btree
    (my_column  int8_ops)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

vs

```
CREATE INDEX my_index_name
    ON public.my_table USING btree
    (my_column)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 18):

As much as I dislike quoting verbatim, I think what is written in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/indexes-opclass.html) describes it most correctly and succintly, and I doubt I could do better:

> The operator class identifies the operators to be used by the index
>   for that column. For example, a B-tree index on the type int4 would
>   use the int4_ops class; this operator class includes comparison
>   functions for values of type int4. In practice the default operator
>   class for the column's data type is usually sufficient. **The main
>   reason for having operator classes is that for some data types, there
>   could be more than one meaningful index behavior**. For example, we
>   might want to sort a complex-number data type either by absolute value
>   or by real part. We could do this by defining two operator classes for
>   the data type and then selecting the proper class when making an
>   index. The operator class determines the basic sort ordering (which
>   can then be modified by adding sort options COLLATE, ASC/DESC and/or
>   NULLS FIRST/NULLS LAST).

---

As for your example, if `my_column` is defined as type `int8`, then specifying the operator class as `int8_ops` is moot, as that would be the default operator for that type.

Comment: Perfect answer. Quoting actually *improves* the quality, I think.